# How to insert with where clause with a specific reference

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, where-clause, sql-insert

Hope I would find a simple solution from you. I am battling to manage insert with where clause with a specific reference. I am using C# 4.5.

```
table name : tbl_image 
id          img
meal001     <binary data>
meal002     NULL
```

If I click button to add an image for meal002, I need to write insert query like this:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_Image (img) SELECT @img from tbl_Image WHERE id = 'meal002'";
```

This query is not working. `Img` column is still `NULL` for `meal002` that already existed in the id column. How to solve this problem?

Your code example would be much appreciated. Thanks!!!!

Comment: C# 4.5 does not exist, and anyway the Db (version) is more relevant.

Comment: And describe it a little better: does the record 'meal002' already exist?

Comment: yes meal002 is already existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> yes meal002 is already existed.

Then you need an UPDATE statement, not an INSERT.

The query should look like

```
UPDATE tbl_Image SET img = @img 
WHERE id = 'meal002'
```

and of course it would make good sense to use a paramter for the Id as well:

```
UPDATE tbl_Image SET img = @img 
WHERE id = @id
```